# While trying to send mail using MS ews java API. recieving PKIX path failed exception though authentication is perfect

Tags: java, certificate, exchangewebservices, pkix

While trying to send mail using MS ews java API. recieving PKIX path failed exception though authentication is perfect. Please find the below error message.I was able to connect to server from where I have to get the content of the mail and it worked till two days ago. Is this because of any change in the JRE of Server machine? which I have no access.

Oracle JDBC Driver Registered! 
Connection successful! 
Connection closed. 
Exception in thread "main" microsoft . exchange . webservices . data.ServiceRequestException: The request Failed. sun . security.vaIidator.VaIidatorException: PKIX path building Failed: sun . security. provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuiIderException: unable to Find valid certification path to requested target 
at microsoft.exchange.webservices . data.ServiceRequestBase .getEwsHttpWebResponse (Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0):

Using below code.

```
final Email email = new Email();

String host = hostname;
Integer port = portNumber;
String from = emailFrom;
String pass = emailFromPassword;
String[] to = emailTo;

String msgBody = "Hello";
email.setFromAddress("", from);
email.setSubject("Demo");
for (int i = 0; i < to.length; i++) {
  email.addRecipient("", to[i], RecipientType.TO);
}
}
email.setTextHTML(msgBody);

new Mailer(host, port, from, pass).sendMail(email);
```

Comment: Please fix the brackets.